# How to destripe a Landsat 7 collection instead of single images in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, landsat-7, fill, gap

I am trying to calculate the *NDMI index* from Landsat 7 collection in GEE.
I have the following code, however a major issue is the gaps.
I had a look [in this example](https://code.earthengine.google.com/d20cba5268ccbe117e2fc1c5fefc33f3). To my understanding, I must set source and fill images and I have no idea why or which one to select. How can I implement this code to the full Landsat collection instead of single images?

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_TOA')
 .filterBounds(geometry)
    .map(function(image){return image.clip(geometry)})
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(7,8,'month'))
    .filterDate('2002-01-01','2017-12-30');
var geometry = /* color: #98ff00 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[111.45822203277788, 36.34333902059149],
          [110.42550718902788, 35.34593714064014],
          [111.94162047027788, 34.698156543400835],
          [112.95236265777788, 35.63218799365042]]]);
          
          
    var qal = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('BQA');
  var mask = qa.eq(672);
  return image.updateMask(mask).copyProperties(image);
}

var clean = dataset.map(qal);

////HERE SHOULD BE THE DESTRIPE CODE

var ndmiFunction = function(image) {
  return image.addBands(image.expression(
    '(nir - swir) / (nir + swir)', {
      nir: image.select('B4'),
      swir: image.select('B5'),
    }).rename('NDMI').clamp(-1, 1));
};

var ndmi = clean.map(ndmiFunction);
var NDMI = ndmi.select('NBR');
```

Comment: What do you intend to do with the gap filled images?  Knowing that would help identify an appropriate method.

Comment: Hi @Noel, I want to calculate vegetation and moisture  indices like the NVI and NDMI. So I want to calculate this indices per image and then take their mean annual values.

Comment: There's no value in gap-filling if you're just going to compute the annual mean value.  You can just take the mean of the original data directly.

Comment: Thnak you @NoelGorelick, just a question thoug, how to deal with points that fall in the gaps? Maybe I miss something.

Comment: If you're taking an annual mean, there won't be any gaps.  You'll just have some spots with a smaller denominator.